# FCM push notifications are not working on TestFlight after some time

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, apple-push-notifications, testflight

I have uploaded a build to Testflight and started testing the push notifications which were developed using Firebase. I used distribution certificate for TestFlight build and also set the setApnsToken to prod. The entitlement file is generated by enabling push notifications and background mode with Remote Notification.
While testing, i have received 23 notifications and then it suddenly stopped receiving notifications.

I checked the device token n it's registered. The device token is same for both i.e. for successfully delivered notifications and failed to receive notifications.

I tried for 2 days but the same thing is happening.

Note.-

1. I am using the single device to test.
2. I am sending device token at the time of login by using InstanceID.
3. The device token is cleared on user logout at the server side.
4. The device token is always registered at the time of login (checked the entries at server side).

Any help is very much appreciated. THANKS IN ADVANCE